# Java Optional<List<T>> to Map conversion

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
    public Map<String, Details> getAllDetails(final String name) {
        Optional<List<JobExecution>> allJobExecutionsByName = Optional.ofNullable(jobExecutionDao.getAllJobExecutionsByName(name));

//        return allJobExecutionsByName.map(x -> x.stream()
//                                                    .map(execution -> Pair.of(getJobParam(execution, "id"), getDetailsFromExecution(execution)))
//                                                    .collect(toList()))
//                                         .orElse(emptyList());

    }
```

Instead of returning `List<Pair<String, Details>>`, I want to return `Map<String, Details>`

How can I convert `Optional<List<JobExecution>>` to a Map with the key being `id` and value being the `Detail` object?

Comment: Have you tried mapping over it? With lambda you can do .map(element -> element.getField,getOtherfield)

Comment: I got it working with list only, but unsure how it would look with optional List

Comment: I'm looking at your commented out code. I guess this is what you did with List? I guess either you can look for a Collect(toMap()) option. Or you could take it as a list and turn that list into a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answer suggests that you can use `Collectors.toMap`, but additionally based on the tags, you **should not use `Optional` in your current context**.

```
public Map<String, Details> getAllDetails(final String name) {
    List<JobExecution>> allJobExecutionsByName = jobExecutionDao.getAllJobExecutionsByName(name);
    
    // perform below check only if you cannot control the returned value above
    if(allJobExecutionsByName == null) return Collections.emptyMap();
    
    return allJobExecutionsByName.stream()
                .collect(Collector.toMap(e -> getJobParam(e, "id"),
                                     e -> getDetailsFromExecution(e))));
}
```

Comment: Good catch! In the question and title asked for convert from `Optional<List<T>>` maybe that why I missed that part OP creating optional inside function.

Comment: @Rono Its actually questionable right from the point when the data is represented as `Optional<List<T>>`. There must be a very good reason to represent it in such a form. (I haven't yet experienced the need for that in our projects.)

Comment: Just realized I also don't use for `Optional<List<T>>` means optional for list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collector.toMap` to collect as Map

```
return allJobExecutionsByName.map(x -> 
          x.stream()
           .collect(Collector.toMap(e -> getJobParam(e, "id"),
                                    e -> getDetailsFromExecution(e))))
       .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is null, just return empty list and proceed streaming an empty list.

```
allJobExecutionsByName.orElse(Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        (e -> getJobParam(e, "id"),
        e -> getDetailsFromExecution(e))
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem, so I did something like this:

```
    public Map<String, Details> getAllDetails(final String name) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jobExecutionDao.getAllJobExecutionsByName(name))
                .map(x -> x.stream()
                .collect(Collector.toMap(e -> getJobParam(e, "id"), e -> getDetailsFromExecution(e)))
                .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
    }
```